# Angular2 HashLocationStrategy always redirects to root

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using `HashLocationStrategy` in my `app.module` as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

My `app-routing.module` is defined as:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'live', loadChildren: 'app/live/live.module#LiveModule' }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When I navigate to root url, it redirects me correctly to `home`, however when I try to navigate to `/live` I still get redirected to home. When I use `/#/live` it loads `LiveModule` correctly.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I have problems with hashlocationstrategy in production when hitting enter second time on URL not calling my backend

Answer (score -2):

As per [Angular 2](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts) seed the Imports in @NgModule has syntax for hash strategy is as follow:

RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, { useHash: true })

Hope it helps

Comment: The problem is not how to use HashLocation, but that it always redirects me back to home page